# Webkit embedded browser disable cookies

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I'm using this borwser in .net 3.5 winform application, on x86 platform.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

The problem, when I logged in facebook, with this browser, and I've got the data from facebook, and I closed the form, and after I reloaded the form (every control recreated) the facebook logged again. So the session continued. I don't want this, I'would like to  begin a new session. Can I disable the cookies of browser, or reset session, or something like this?

```
   public WebBrowserTabPage currentPage;

   WebBrowserTabPage page = new WebBrowserTabPage();
   tabControl.TabPages.Add(page);
   currentPage = page;
   currentPage.browser.Navigate(Url);
```

currentPage.browser is a WebKitBrowser instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen about my problem, and I found a variable (CookiesPolicy in WebkitBrowser class. I've set up this to disable cookies, and facebook didn't worked without cookies. I've tried to delete the WebkitBrowser's cookies from hard drive, but I didn't find them. After I've dicovered, there is a memory leak with Webkitbrowser. So I closed the from, but it didn't disposed, and stayed in memory. Finally I solved the problem, I've put the WebkitBrowser in another Project, and I'm running in different Application.
I'm using Inter Process Communication (IPM) for communicating between mother form application and the browser application
 After the browsers

```
 Application.Exit();
```

the session is disposed, and I can sign into facebook again.

Here is the sample code for IPM with named Pipe:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34073/Inter-Process-Communication-IPC-Introduction-and-S